# Is there a way to use mss and pytesseract witchout saving and open?

Tags: python-imaging-library, python-tesseract, python-mss

Need to use mss witchout saving and open images in order to "optimize" this task here is mine code and sorry my bad english.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import mss
import mss.tools

with mss.mss() as sct:

    monitor = {'top': 171, 'left': 1090, 'width': 40, 'height': 17}
    output = 'capture.png'.format(**monitor)

    sct_img = sct.grab(monitor)

    mss.tools.to_png(sct_img.rgb, sct_img.size, output=output)

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('capture.png'))

    print(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind using Numpy?

```
import mss
import numpy
import pytesseract


monitor = {'top': 171, 'left': 1090, 'width': 40, 'height': 17}
with mss.mss() as sct:
    im = numpy.array(sct.grab(monitor), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    im = numpy.flip(im[:, :, :3], 2)  # BGRA -> RGB conversion
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
    print(text)
```

A simple one shot time comparison gives me:

```
MSS.tools + PIL: 0.00988 s
MSS + Numpy    : 0.00222 s
```

Comment: Its not working for my, i tested it in debian stable with python3 + numpy + mss + pytesseract im new with this libraries.

Comment: and i don't have any errors but don't know why its not working

Comment: Can you explain this: dtype=numpy.uint8) im = numpy.flip(im[:, :, :3], 2)? i need to understand X.X im new with numpy u.u

Comment: I just added a comment for the `flip()` usage. By default, MSS returns an array with pixels in BGRA order; the flip will rearrange into RGB. `dtype` it is the type of each value in the array, it is the default value but interestingly it is a little faster when specifying it directly.

Comment: Is it okay for you?